# How does the 12x exp boost work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

To celebrate May 4th, subscribers got a 12x exp boost on class missions. As of July 17th, subscribers are still getting this boost. Apparently the only way to stop the boost is to buy an item from a vendor on the fleet. I've also heard that completing missions that are not class missions will get rid of the boost. Is this true?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because 12x XP has been removed and is very unlikely to return, given Level Sync and the altered quest paths introduced in 4.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in regards to an old game mechanic that is no longer available to player through legal application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> May 4th, subscribers got a 12x exp boost on class missions. As of July 17th, subscribers are still getting this boost. Apparently the only way to stop the boost is to buy an item from a vendor on the fleet.

All true (though the item is free).  It continues until early access for the the next expansion, Knights of the Fallen Empire, on October 20th.  Note that Ilum and Makeb planetary storylines count as "class missions" for the purpose of this boost as long as you are below level 55, whereas Rishi and Yavin do not.

> I've also heard that completing missions that are not class missions will get rid of the boost. Is this true?

Not even remotely, I'm sorry to say you were mislead.

---

Some more details: http://www.swtor.com/blog/epic-story-xp-boost